# is it possible to set the max file size upload in Rails and NGINX for a particular extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn

I want to allow 10mb file size for audio files like mp3,wma, but not for images and other kind of extensions, help on that would be much appreciated.

```
client_max_body_size 10M
```

Comment: I think this is off-topic for Stack Overflow and would fit better on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [PapaeClip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave), then yes. it is possible.

If using `PaperClip`, it has a validator called `validates_attachment_size`

If using `CarrierWave`, [see this](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Validate-attachment-file-size) to learn how to validate attachment size